# Dovecot log file location on Nixos

Tags: dovecot, nixos

I want to use dovecot as a local IMAP server to serve my offlineimap synced mails to gnus. This is on a Nixos installation. I have installed the dovecot package via my configuration.nix. however I am having trouble configuring it, seeing where the log files are, etc. I copy the configuration files (dovecot.conf and config.d) from /nix/store/dovecot/share/doc/dovecot/example-config. I can then modify slightly the files to allow plain login (no ssl required) just to test.I can start dovecot (as root). I see the process running, the relevant ports are open and listening, e.g. 143. Everything looks OK. No crashes. However when I telnet localhost 143 (for imap) to test, I am connected and then immediately the connection is closed by foreign host. This is not what I expect from the Dovecot Wiki. I should get a statement that Dovecot is ready …

Additionally, the command doveadm log find responds with:

Looking for log files from /var/log Debug: Not found Info: Not found etc.

So there seem to be no log files. journalctl -u dovecot2.service shows logs begin …, end at …

No entries, so no issues ? I cannot find a log file which tells me why the connection on 143 is immediately closed.

I am at a loss what is going on. Is it to do with users needed, etc ? Appreciate any help. Can post doveconf -n if needed.

Comment: It's probably best to provide a single question as it's a bit hard to follow what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the configuration file for dovecot2 here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/mail/dovecot.nix#L344 as `dovecot2` is the name of the service `journalctl -u dovecot2` should be the right command to run to view its logs. That said, if for some reason there's a bug in the configuration module the command `journalctl` will show you the complete log, dovecot's included.

It would be nice if you had written here your configuration, because given that the configuation entries for dovecot are those listed here https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.dovecot2 it's not clear to me what you mean when you write `... I copy the configuration files (dovecot.conf and config.d) from /nix/store/dovecot/share/doc/dovecot/example-config ..`. The configuration in nixos is comprised for the most part of Nix source files that specify entries in the NixOS configuration tree I've linked before.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing things completely wrong. I now specify the dovecot service to start in my configuration.nic file and it sets up the correct environment with all config files in their correct place. To change options in the config file, e.g maildir, I now specify them also in the configuration.nix file. Thanks for your answer.